# set variable in $watch sometimes fails?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Using Angular 1.0.7:

I've a directive which is meant to display a styled checkbox.

[See plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Al5cEu5WDs7ZwxZpk9wO?p=preview).

***Sometimes*** (and not always) my watcher doesnt update one of my scope's variable see:

Here is a failing sequence:

- foo
- bar
- all
- foo
- bar

[image]

I wonder why the update doesnt occur.

Comment: im not sure i follow your issue? everything works for me when i click on foo,bar each time no fail...

Comment: this is where the ***sometimes*** makes things difficult, let me try to find a failing sequence

Comment: got one, added in question

Comment: I hate to say it but `$watchCollection` is a great resolution for this, however it came about in Angular 1.1.4

Comment: but the watcher works fine, just the setter which does not

Comment: @apneadiving Yeah, sorry I didn't notice this the first time I looked at it. Very interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was very interesting question, so problem with combination of your **clicked** handler and **preferences.email** watch:

angularjs code:

```
//https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js line 4510
scope.$watch(function parentValueWatch() {
    var parentValue = parentGet(parentScope);

    if (parentValue !== scope[scopeName]) {
        // we are out of sync and need to copy
        if (parentValue !== lastValue) {
            // parent changed and it has precedence
            lastValue = scope[scopeName] = parentValue;
        } else {
            // if the parent can be assigned then do so
            parentSet(parentScope, parentValue = lastValue = scope[scopeName]);
        }
    }
    return parentValue;
});
break;
```

You are starting with click on **foo + bar** and we have:

```
all: true
foo: true
bar: true
```

Click by **toggle all**:

```
//by this code
var new_val = toggled_input_value();
$scope.model = new_val;
```

$scope.model is **scope[scopeName]** from the above code, so scope[scopeName] = false and lastValue = true, parentValue = true (they will be change after $digest run)

```
$scope.clicked({ value: new_val });
```

will call

```
$scope.toggleAll = function(new_value){
  if (new_value){
    $scope.preferences.email.foo = true;
    $scope.preferences.email.bar = true;
  }
  else{
    $scope.preferences.email.foo = false;
    $scope.preferences.email.bar = false;    
  }
}
```

so,

```
all: true - $digest have not been run
foo: false
bar: false
```

and, begin $digest... first call will be:

```
$scope.$watch('preferences.email', function(new_value){
  var bool = new_value.foo && new_value.bar;
  $scope.preferences.all = bool;
}, true);
```

so,

```
all: false
foo: false
bar: false
```

it's a problem, because on the next **parentValueWatch** call we'll get:

```
parentValue = false //$scope.preferences.all
scope[scopeName] = false //$scope.model
lastValue = true
```

so, **parentValue === scope[scopeName]**, and lastValue have not been updated... it's a bug:)

when you will change $scope.preferences.all to the true, you will get

```
$scope.preferences.all === lastValue //true
```

and call

```
// if the parent can be assigned then do so
parentSet(parentScope, parentValue = lastValue = scope[scopeName]);
```

so, $scope.preferences.all will become false, instead of a true

you can look at this here http://plnkr.co/edit/YEHqA101YwWKDvK6odFf?p=preview (console.trace)

Comment: my issue is that if I use the callback, the controller still bears a non updated object. That's why I used $watch which is not a good idea too apparently :)

Comment: + since I get the initial checkbox values from the dom and not from a js object, I have issues to know the initial state...

Comment: do you know if there is a way to call the callback once model is **really** updated?

Comment: yep, it have been fixed some time ago https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5182
you can use angular version 1.2.4 and later

but, if you need 1.0.7 version, you can use a hack with $timeout:
http://plnkr.co/edit/0g9VX7fCDuZMWCiPYHRY?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

There is a TON of code you have that you don't need. Some of that code, not exactly sure which line, is interfering. Mainly, you don't need to manually set the model on the checkbox, when you set `ng-model='model'` in your template, that's all you need!

So here's the working forked version of your code which works: http://plnkr.co/edit/CzhiAVEAuDtiL2QO95Za and as you can see I removed almost everything you did relating to the model, as it's all automatic.

Let's summarize what we did:

1. removed the pre-compile code, unless you need name to be defined before compile? not sure why.
2. no need for input value functions, it's true or false right? That's done automatically by the model.
3. $scope.select should just toggle the model value, everything else is automatic.
4. removed init function, model value is automatically set anyway
5. removed the **deep** watch from inside the directive, you don't need DEEP watch here as you're passing it the lowest values and it's not worried about other values. The outer toggle function is the only thing worried about deep watching.

Simplified directive code:

```
app.directive("uuCheckbox", function() {
return {
  restrict: "A",
  transclude: true,
  scope: {
    model: '=',
    clicked: '&'
  },
  template: "<div ng-click='select()'>" + 
    "<span ng-class='{ checked: model }'></span>" + 
    "<input class='hidden' value='true' type='checkbox' ng-model='model'>" + 
    "<span ng-class='{red: model}' ng-transclude></span>" + 
  "</div>",
  compile: function(elmt, tAttrs) {
    return function($scope, element, attrs) {
      element.find('input').attr('name', attrs.name);
      var on_change = function(new_value) {
        $scope.clicked({ value: new_value });
      };
      $scope.$watch('model', on_change);
      $scope.select = function() {
        $scope.model = !$scope.model;
      };
    };
  }
};
});
```

Comment: I need the precompile because the checkbox must appear checked if the html property checked is present, thats one of the option I pass the same way as the name (but removed in my example to show minimal code)

Comment: and a checkbox is not simply true/false, it can have any value or false (so yes I need to get the value I pass in args)

Comment: wondering how to pass the proper value to the model without hacking the input val

Comment: you are facing the same bug as me but it's not the same way: click all, then click foo, everything will be false where bar should have remained true. But thanks for your advice, +1